# Logisim 7 segment display

Tags: circuit

I am trying to create a circuit in Logisim that can count upwards using the 7-segment display as the output. It needs to run using a clock, and automatically count from 0 to 9 and then back to 0 again, in a continuous loop. I don't know where to start on this and I was wondering if anyone has any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post what you've tried

Comment: All I've done so far is create each number individually on the 7 segment display. I know which segments need to be lit up for each number, but no idea how to make it count from 0 to 9 automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use ROM, along with a binary to BCD converter. Look up the double dabble algorithm- useful for your purpose.